# install daewr package in R 4.0

Tags: r

hi i am trying to install package for experiment designs like this

```
install.packages("daewr", dependencies = T)
```

but it returns the following

```
configure: error: GNU MP not found, or not 4.1.4 or up, see http://gmplib.org
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gmp’
* removing ‘/home/yeferson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/gmp’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gmp’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘gmp’ is not available for package ‘partitions’
* removing ‘/home/yeferson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/partitions’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘partitions’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘partitions’ is not available for package ‘DoE.base’
* removing ‘/home/yeferson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/DoE.base’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘DoE.base’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘DoE.base’ is not available for package ‘FrF2’
* removing ‘/home/yeferson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/FrF2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘FrF2’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘FrF2’ is not available for package ‘daewr’
* removing ‘/home/yeferson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/daewr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘daewr’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpB1bSe0/downloaded_packages’
```

so i decided to download the file from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/daewr/index.html

after trying to install it returns me

```
also installing the dependencies ‘gmp’, ‘partitions’, ‘DoE.base’, ‘FrF2.catlg128’
```

I try to install the first one but it asks for a Bessel package and it still gives me problems

Comment: I suspect you're on Linux.  If so, the path of least resistance might be to add this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u and install the binary package

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing dependency one by one, many answer you install the dependencies but they do not say how I will explain them for the new ones in linux and in R to install the daerw package with the aforementioned problems, install the following in the linux console

```
 sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev
```

with that install libraries now I can open R and install

```
install.packages('gsl')

then I opened the linux console again and installed
```

sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev

```
I go back to R and install
```

install.packages("gmp", dependencies = T)

```
now I can install the package without problems
```

install.packages("daewr", dependencies = T)

library(daewr)

```
I hope that any comment is welcome.
```